# ASP.NET Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have no problem in local. But I get this error in uploaded website:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

In [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810098) link it says this is a bug with ADO but I dont use ADO in my code.

Here is my code:

```
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
        sc.ConnectionString = MyConnectionString;
        sc.Open();
        SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(INSERT COMMAND);
        scm.Connection = sc;
        scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sc.Close();
```

I put my above code in `USING` statements and nothing changed.

Here is my stack trace

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>   Register.BtnRegister_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) +601
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +115
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +120
>
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

And here is `BtnRegister_Click` code:

```
    protected void BtnRegister_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
    if (TxtName.Text == "" || TxtFamily.Text == "" || txtNationalCode.Text == "" || TxtIdNumber.Text == "" || txtMobile.Text == "" || TxtEmail.Text == "" || txtAddress.Text == "" || TxtSecurityCode.Text == "")
    {
        LblMsg.Text = "You should fill all fields";
        return;
    }

    if (txtNationalCode.Text.Length != 10)
    {
        LblMsg.Text = "National code must have 10 digits";
        return;
    }

    if (txtMobile.Text.Length != 11)
    {
        LblMsg.Text = "Mobile number should have 11 digits";
        return;
    }

    if (T_Paticipant.GetDataByNationalCode(txtNationalCode.Text).Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        LblMsg.Text = "This national code used before";
        return;
    }

    if (T_Paticipant.GetDataByEmail(TxtEmail.Text).Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        LblMsg.Text = "This email used before";
        return;
    }

    LblMessage.Text = "Are you sure to register?";
    LblFlag.Text = "0";


    //captcha

    if (this.Session["CaptchaImageText"].ToString().ToLower() == TxtSecurityCode.Text.ToLower())
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showMessage()", "<script>ShowMessage() </script>");
    }
    else
    {
        LblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        LblMsg.Text = "Security code is wrong";
    }
    //end captcha
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Aside from anything else, you should be using `using` statements to close your commands and connections.

Comment: Can you post which line of code you got that exception on?

Comment: @NickW: I dont know how to debug it line by line, because its not local, I uploaded it.

Comment: Now you don't assign the Connection to the Command and you should show what `INSERT COMMAND` is.

Comment: it's not a bug, it's the way you handle the code.

Comment: @masoudkeshavarz: If you haven't got logging which will show you the stack trace, that's the *first* thing to fix.

Comment: I used `using` statement and nothing changed. Also I dont have any error in local. I updated my question. Thank you for help.

Comment: Would you be able to post the contents of the `BtnRegister_Click` method?

Comment: @NickW: it is a long code, and for avoiding mistakes I put all of them without change.

Comment: What's `T_Paticipant`? That appears to be defined elsewhere - could it be null when you are trying to use it? I would also check that `this.Session["CaptchaImageText"]` is not null before using it.

Comment: `T_Paticipant` is a TableAdapter from a XSD file. I have no idea how to check if they are null or not. Because i uploaded it. And they have no problem when I test them in local.

Comment: is it possible this two statements return a null value and throw exception? `if (T_Paticipant.GetDataByNationalCode(txtNationalCode.Text).Rows.Count > 0)` `if (T_Paticipant.GetDataByEmail(TxtEmail.Text).Rows.Count > 0)
`

Comment: Sure is. Putting in checks for these sorts of things would make you code a lot more robust.

Comment: Problem is because of `this.Session["CaptchaImageText"]`

Comment: Thank you everyone for help. This error occurred because value of a session was null and ToString() method couldn't find any data to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for help.
This error occurred because value of a `session` was null and `ToString()` method couldn't find any data to convert.

Answer (score 2):

set the `connectionstring` first before opening

```
    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
    sc.ConnectionString = MyConnectionString
    SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(INSERT COMMAND);
    scm.Connection = sc;           // missing this.
    sc.Open();
    scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sc.Close();
```

or

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstringhere"))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = "your query";
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        // comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName","value"); // if you have parameters
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            // error here
            // ex.Message.Tostring  // holds the error message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, But it was correct in my code. In here I writed it wrong

Comment: @masoudkeshavarz check my updated answer. set connection to your command.

Comment: @masoudkeshavarz: You *must* make sure you post your actual code in future. There's no point in us finding bugs in irrelevant code. It's worth taking an extra few minutes to make sure your question is as good as it can be before posting. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: yes im really sorry. next time I post question after I was sure. Im sorry again.

Comment: I used `using` statement just like you said and nothing changed. Also I dont have any error in local. I updated my question. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `new SqlCommand(query, sc)`